# Why is this Activity Search failing?

Tags: activity, sql

Activity Search is failing every time for this install (Search/Find Activities) no matter what search parameters are used. The problem is the following SQL error:

*SELECT count( DISTINCT ( civicrm_activity.id ) ) as rowCount  FROM civicrm_contact contact_a   LEFT JOIN civicrm_activity_contact
ON ( civicrm_activity_contact.contact_id = contact_a.id )  LEFT JOIN civicrm_activity
ON ( civicrm_activity.id = civicrm_activity_contact.activity_id
AND civicrm_activity.is_deleted = 0 AND civicrm_activity.is_current_revision = 1 ) INNER JOIN civicrm_contact
ON ( civicrm_activity_contact.contact_id = civicrm_contact.id and civicrm_contact.is_deleted != 1 )  LEFT JOIN civicrm_activity_contact source_activity
ON (source_activity.activity_id = civicrm_activity_contact.activity_id
AND source_activity.record_type_id = 2)
LEFT JOIN civicrm_contact source_contact ON (source_activity.contact_id = source_contact.id)  WHERE  ( civicrm_activity.activity_type_id IN ("110") AND civicrm_activity.status_id IN ("1", "2") AND civicrm_activity.is_test = 0 )  AND  (  ( civicrm_activity.activity_type_id IN (110,135,136,120,1,2,3,116,4,9,12,5,6,19,22,34,40,44,37,38,39,45,41,42,43,52,49,50,46,47,48,51,64,114,115,68,73,74,75,76,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,96,97,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,111,113,117,118,119,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,130,131,133,134,137,138,139,140,141,142,143) )  )  AND (contact_a.is_deleted = 0) AND (civicrm_activity.activity_type_id Array)


the error message is 'check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Array)' at line 8]*'

As you can see this install has a ***lot*** of activity types - could this be the reason? The last 'AND' statement seems to be the problem.  This is on 5.28.3 and activity search is working fine on other 5.28.3 systems. Also there seems to be no limit on the number of items in the 'IN' clause in MySQL.

Comment: Do you have some ACL or extension that restricts by types? It's not the amount - what's happening is there's supposed to be a string but it's getting a php array, so it's a coding error somewhere.

Comment: Yes indeed (my, that was a fast response!). We have the Activity ACL extension installed (ACL for Activity Types).  I didn't think it looked like that was relevant...wrong?

Comment: See https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.activitytypeacl/pull/14

Comment: Many thanks, I'll test and will confirm if that's the answer. I looked at that site but it wasn't in the list of issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the same problem as https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.activitytypeacl/pull/14

Comment: Thanks for this - 47 minutes from reporting the problem and the fix is now installed!

Comment: Great! Glad it's working.